# Transform in a parent div is "overriding" the transform in the child div

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue where my parent div's transform attribute is overriding the child div, and causing it to mess up its placement.

Even when I set `transform: none` on the child div, it still continues to override.

Here is the parent's CSS style:

```
.centeredTextPhoto {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here is the child's CSS style:

```
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1000; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 170px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    transform: none
}
```

Comment: text-transform: none !important;

Comment: I avoid `!important` most of the time. Instead find a way to make the child selector more specific like: `.centeredTextPhoto .modal { transform: none; }`

Comment: do the inverse transformation

Comment: Showing your HTML would help.

Answer (score -2):

You can try with the `!important` element at the end of you style.

```
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1000; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 170px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    transform: none !important
}
```

It will overwrite any existing `transform` style.

Comment: it is always better to provide better specificity then to use `!important` https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/